# Trying to convert xml text into xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Im trying to convert an XML from a source system into a same xml in c#

From

```
<root>
 <child>&lt;xml&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;</child>
</root>
```

To

```
<root>
 <child><![CDATA[<xml></xml>]]></child>
</root>
```

I tried following to arrive this

```
var node = resXML.SelectSingleNode(@"/root/child");
node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(node.AppendChild(resXML.CreateCDataSection(encodedXML)), node);
```

with below Output

```
<root>
<![CDATA[<xml></xml>]]>
</root>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string xml = "<root><child>&lt;xml&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;</child></root>";

XmlDocument resXML = new XmlDocument();
resXML.LoadXml(xml);
var node = resXML.SelectSingleNode(@"/root/child");
node.AppendChild(resXML.CreateCDataSection(node.InnerText));
node.RemoveChild(node.FirstChild);

string output = resXML.OuterXml;
```

Comment: This worked for me except for the part of InnerText ,which always encodes the XML content. so I explicitly converted them.                               string xml = "<root><child>&lt;xml&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;</child></root>";

XmlDocument resXML = new XmlDocument();
resXML.LoadXml(xml);
var node = resXML.SelectSingleNode(@"/root/child"); 
var xmlFormat=ConverttoXML(node.InnerText); //A custom function which returns <xml></xml> as value 

node.AppendChild(resXML.CreateCDataSection(xmlFormat));
node.RemoveChild(node.FirstChild);
string output = resXML.OuterXml;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sourceXml = "<root><child>&lt;xml&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;</child></root>";

var source = XDocument.Parse(sourceXml);

var result = new XDocument(new XElement("root",
                    source.Root
                          .Elements("child")
                          .Select(e => new XElement("child", new XCData(e.Value)))));

var resultXml = result.ToString();
```